# Flight LH 8371 appears on flight trackers but not anywhere on the Lufthansa website. Why?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, lufthansa

Searching for HYD-SHJ flights on the Lufthansa site doesnt yield results, nor does tracking the flight on Lufthansa. But the flight shows up on [flightstats](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByRoute.do?departure=%28HYD%29%20Rajiv%20Gandhi%20Intl%2C%20Hyderabad%2C%20IN&arrival=%28SHJ%29%20Sharjah%20Intl%2C%20Sharjah%2C%20AE&departureDate=2014-07-03&x=24&y=15) and other trackers.

Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be a [cargo flight](http://info.flightmapper.net/flight/Lufthansa_LH_8371); you can find it on the [Lufthansa Cargo](http://lufthansa-cargo.com/) website.

Comment: Yup..  that explains it weird of Google and flightstats to track it in a normal manner, other cargo flights arent tracked like that

Answer (score 5):

Like most airlines, Lufthansa follow a fixed numbering schema for their flights.

As per [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufthansa) (in German), their current flight numbering schema, which they changed to in late 2010 includes :

LH8000 – LH8515 Flüge der Lufthansa Cargo

ie, Flight numbers between LH8000 and LH8515 are Flights for Lufthansa Cargo.

As your flight number calls within this range, it's obviously a cargo flight.  Unlike many of their passenger flights, Lufthansa do not (publicly, at least) base cargo flight numbers on region, and thus this flight number could be used between any two locations.